# AndroidRuntime(28869): Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class

Tags: android, java, view

Здравствуйте! Пишу приложение, в котором реализованы темы. Однако при их использовании вылетает.
Лог:

```
<item>
<item>

03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at moriveon.simpleplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     ... 11 more
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     ... 27 more
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/seek_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020006
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1954)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:73)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:83)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:79)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     ... 30 more
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1951)
03-26 19:03:01.601 E/AndroidRuntime(28869):     ... 34 more
```

seek_progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="?seek_secondary" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="?seek_primary" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seek_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="?seek_disabled" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="?seek_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="?seek_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="?seek_normal" />
</selector>
```

Кусок attrs.xml:

```
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_disabled" />
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_focused" />
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_normal" />
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_pressed" />
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_primary" />
    <attr format="integer|reference" name="seek_secondary" />
```

Кусок разметки, из-за котого выкидывает:

```
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/main_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seek_selector"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_progress" />
```

В styles.xml каждый элемент имеет вид типа `<item name="...">@drawable/...</item>`
Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Попробуйте: `<attr format="reference" name="seek_disabled" />` - то есть без `integer|`

Comment: @Barmaley, попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: так не получится. Только @drawable/...

* [RTFM Drawable Resources. State list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)
* [SO:Can a selector resource use a color defined in a style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253458/unable-to-use-color-as-drawable-sometimes)